# What am I doing wrong in trying to *EXACTLY* determine the decimal number of years between two (possibly very distant) dates?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datediff, date-difference

**Current code/example (please read the dates/times carefully):**

```
$a = date_diff(date_create('1980-01-02 15:00:00'), date_create('2020-01-02 15:00:00'));
$average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years = bcdiv($a->days, $a->y);
var_dump(bcdiv($a->days, $average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years));

$a = date_diff(date_create('1980-01-02 15:00:00'), date_create('2020-01-02 15:00:01'));
$average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years = bcdiv($a->days, $a->y);
var_dump(bcdiv($a->days, $average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years));

$a = date_diff(date_create('1980-01-02 15:00:00'), date_create('2020-01-03 15:00:00'));
$average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years = bcdiv($a->days, $a->y);
var_dump(bcdiv($a->days, $average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years));

$a = date_diff(date_create('1980-01-02 15:00:00'), date_create('2020-01-01 15:00:00'));
$average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years = bcdiv($a->days, $a->y);
var_dump(bcdiv($a->days, $average_number_of_days_for_the_relevant_years));
```

**Expected/desired output:**

```
string(102) "40.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "40.000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "40.001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "39.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"
```

**Actual output:**

```
string(102) "40.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "40.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "40.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
string(102) "39.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

**Analysis:**

No matter what I try (and I've tried *countless* things in the past and before asking, today), PHP never seems to let me calculate the accurate "decimal years" between two dates. It either forces me to divide with "365", which will result in increasingly inaccurate numbers the longer the date span is, or do what I do above, which gives me only "integers": somebody is considered to be exactly 39 years exactly up until the very moment when it switches over to 40 years.

I have tried this with `(float)`s too. Same basic issue. I used `bcdiv()` in desperation, thinking that maybe the floats were messing it up with rounding or something like that.

At this point, I truly have no idea what to do. All "solutions" online are horribly wrong. I've looked at a lot of code and they all do it incorrectly. The `date_diff` object sadly only gives me "scattered" data and the total number of days, but no nice decimal/float number for the number of years. I have no idea why they would exclude the most useful piece of data, but they did, and here I am, having wasted ages of my life on this issue alone... which is ironic, since this is about calculating ages.

I will never be able to sleep again until this is finally solved properly and accurately, no matter how far apart the dates are. This kind of thing drives me crazy, and it's typical for me to have a need which isn't met by the existing mechanism, even though it seems to me like the by-far most common desired output.

Can somebody who is really smart please help me figure this out once and for all? (I have no interest in yet another inaccurate solution which falls apart if you compare datetimes a thousand year apart, for example.)

Comment: Is there an _exact_ definition of what “decimal years” are supposed to be somewhere? And especially how leap years are supposed to be taken into account? Whether the start or end date is before or after Feb. 28th in a leap year would have to be taken into account somehow, I suppose?

Comment: @CBroe The percentage of the average length of a year between the two dates.

Comment: Fractions of a unit only make sense if the unit is a fixed quantity. This applies to hours, minutes and seconds. Years and months are not fixed. Fractions of it don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine an exact decimal difference in years between two dates.

Fractions of years can be given for illustration. For example, 3 years and 6 months can be written as 3.5 years.

The humanYearDiff () function supplies such a value for illustration. The result is not accurate and therefore not suitable for further calculations. To simplify matters, the month is also calculated with 31 days.

```
function humanYearDiff(DateTime $start,Datetime $end){
  $diff = $start->diff($end);
  $days = $diff->d + $diff->h/24 + $diff->i/1440 + $diff->s/86400;
  $years = $diff->y + $diff->m/12.0 + $days/372;
  return $diff->invert ? -$years : $years;
}
```

A little test:

```
$testData = [
  ['1980-02-01 15:00','2020-02-01 15:00'],
  ['1980-02-01 15:00','2020-08-01 15:00'],
  ['1980-02-01 15:00','2020-05-01 15:00'],
  ['1980-02-01 15:00','2020-02-01 15:01'],
  ['1980-02-01 15:00','2020-02-01 14:59'],
  ['today','today +6 month'],
];

foreach($testData as $dateStartEnd){
  $floatYear = humanYearDiff(date_create($dateStartEnd[0]),date_create($dateStartEnd[1]));
  echo $dateStartEnd[0].' -> '.$dateStartEnd[1].' = '.$floatYear." Years<br>\n";
}
```

output:

```
1980-02-01 15:00 -> 2020-02-01 15:00 = 40 Years
1980-02-01 15:00 -> 2020-08-01 15:00 = 40.5 Years
1980-02-01 15:00 -> 2020-05-01 15:00 = 40.25 Years
1980-02-01 15:00 -> 2020-02-01 15:01 = 40.000001866786 Years
1980-02-01 15:00 -> 2020-02-01 14:59 = 39.999998133214 Years
today -> today +6 month = 0.5 Years
```